# Using the open(' ', 'w') function but file is not being edited

Tags: python

I'm using the code below to attempt to open a file and edit the text in the file (this is; my string), but after running this code, the file remains unchanged when I open it in my documents. Anyone got an idea why?

```
myfile=open("file","w")
mod= "this is; my string ".split(";")
myfile.write(" ".join(mod))
myfile.close()
```

Comment: That will create "file" in the current directory where the script is running, so make sure you're looking at the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

your code will create file at the directory where the script is running. you should use:

```
  file_path = os.path.abspath(__file__) + "/file"

  f = open(file_path,"w")
  f.write(.....)
  f.close()
```

and then it will create file in the directory you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
with open("file","w+") as myfile:  # Use mode w+
   mod= "this is; my string ".split(";")
   myfile.write(" ".join(mod))
```

using with `open() as x` you do not need to run `.close()`